# Normal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb C$ and $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation. Assume that every eigenvector of $T$ is also an eigenvector of $T^*$.
I need to prove that $TT^*=T^*T$ ($T$ is a normal transformation).
I've managed to show that for all the $V$ subspaces of eigenvectors it is the case.
And if I call the span of all eigenvectors $W$ then the span of non-eigenvectors ($W^\perp$) is orthogonal to it, using that I've shown that $W^\perp$ is an invariant of $T$ and $T^*$ and that's where I'm stuck. It feels like it's close to the end, like there's one last thing missing. Thank you!

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: yes, finite! sorry I didn't mention it

Comment: Is $T^*$ the conjugate transpose of $T$? (Are you identifying $V$ with $V^*$ via a positive definite Hermitian form?)

Comment: I'm not so sure of the question, but the definition of T* is that <Tv,u>=<v,T*u>

Answer (score 2):

Since we are working over a complex inner product space it suffices to show that $V$ has an orthonormal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T$. Again, since we are working over $\mathbb{C}$, we know that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits. Hence by Schur's theorem there exits an orthonormal basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ such that the matrix representation of $T$, say $A$, is upper triangular. By definition, we have that $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $T$. We prove that each $v_i$ is also an eigenvector by induction. Suppose that $v_1,\dots,v_{k-1}$ are eigenvectors for some $k$. For $j<k$, let $\lambda_j$ be the eigenvector corresponding to $v_j$. Since $A$ is upper triangular $$T(v_k)=A_{1k}v_1+A_{2k}v_2+\dots+A_{kk}v_k.$$ Since our basis is orthonormal we have that $$A_{jk}=\langle T(v_k),v_j\rangle=\langle v_k, T^\ast(v_j)\rangle=\langle v_k,\eta_j v_j\rangle=\overline{\eta_j}\langle v_k,v_j\rangle=0$$where $\eta_j$ is the eigenvalue of $T^\ast$ corresponding to $v_j$. Since this holds for all $j<k$ it must be that $T(v_k)=A_{kk}v_k$.

Comment: Please elaborate on the last part, why is v1 an eigenvector? and how is it proven by induction that each vi is indeed an eigenvector itself?

Comment: Where is that taking to affect the fact that both T and T* have the same eigenvectors? am I missing something?

Comment: Because in the induction hypothesis we have that $v_j$ is an eigenvector of $T$. Hence it is also an eigenvector of $T^\ast$. That is, $T^\ast(v_j)=\eta_jv_j$.

Comment: I see, and is there a way to prove it with where I was initially going? sans-induction?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe! You showed that each eigenspace is invariant under $T$ and $T^\ast$. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to directly prove $TT^\ast=T^\ast T$, or use some other theorem that gives normality as a conclusion?

Comment: All will be good, for the eigenvectors I know it is true, and I'm trying to prove it for the all of the others

Comment: Then I believe you would need to show that $V$ is a direct sum of the eigenspaces of $T$.